# Accessing notification bar

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

Is there any API that will allow me to access the notification bar while running my UI-Automation code?

e.g test case

Testing my app:
1. User-A does some update for User-B.
2. User-B's device shows a notification
3. UI Automation wants to access the notification bar of User-B's device to see what the notification is and test the content.

Queries:
1. Is it possible using UI Automation.
2. If not how can this be tested?